# Missing params from body when sandbox environment

Tags: apple-push-notifications, subscription

We are implementing push server notifications and during our tests we are getting way too few parameters in json from apple which makes it impossible to identify the subscription.

Table 6.3 in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) claims that body contains several params amongst `original_transaction_id`, `latest_receipt`, `latest_receipt_info` etc.

Though, we are only getting for `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` type:

```
{
"auto_renew_product_id": "agreement_chat_MO_auto_renewal",
"password": "CORRECT_PASSWORD_HERE",
"environment": "Sandbox",
"auto_renew_status": "false",
"notification_type": "INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL"
}
```

and for `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` type:

```
{
"auto_renew_status_change_date": "2019-06-03 08:13:11 Etc/GMT",
"environment": "Sandbox",
"auto_renew_status": "false",
"auto_renew_status_change_date_pst": "2019-06-03 01:13:11 America/Los_Angeles",
"password": "CORRECT_PASSWORD_HERE",
"auto_renew_status_change_date_ms": "1559549591000",
"auto_renew_product_id": "the_product_id",
"notification_type": "DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS"
}
```

Given those params, it is impossible to find the subscription the notification refers at.

Am I missing something here? Is the sandbox broken in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not the only one...
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/116996

It has been broken in Sandbox for days now. We checked our logs and they had this error in production for some time. Now in production it seems to be fixed, but the problem persists in Sandbox.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: They FINALLY seem to have fixed it in Sandbox. We have received a well constructed notification now.